# Query results same when using xml raw,element and xml path

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I am using sql-server 2012:

I have query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #XmlTestTable 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName VARCHAR(20),
    LastName VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #XmlTestTable (FirstName,LastName) VALUES
('John','Doe'),
('Jane','Doe'),
('Brian','Smith'),
('Your','Mom')

SELECT * FROM #XmlTestTable FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS --1
SELECT * FROM #XmlTestTable FOR XML PATH --2
```

Result of 1:

```
<row>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <FirstName>Brian</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <FirstName>Your</FirstName>
  <LastName>Mom</LastName>
</row>
```

Result of 2:

```
<row>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <FirstName>Brian</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <FirstName>Your</FirstName>
  <LastName>Mom</LastName>
</row>
```

both the queries give same results,?

How do I find out the difference and when to use xml path or xml elements
Sql-server 2012 compiled on.

Comment: Check here for difference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175140.aspx

Comment: You asked a question that is an answer to a question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094866/in-sqlserver-2012-tsql-whats-the-difference-of-using-xml-raw-xml-auto-and-xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RAW` mode transforms each row in the query result set into an XML element that has the generic identifier `<row>`, or the optionally provided element name.

Each column value in the rowset that is not NULL is mapped to an **attribute** of the `<row>` element, but if you've specified `ELEMENTS` option, columns values will be mapped to **subelements**, not attributes.

In `PATH` mode, column names or column aliases are treated as `XPath` expressions. These expressions indicate how the values are being mapped to XML. Each XPath expression is a relative XPath that provides the item type., such as the attribute, element, and scalar value, and the name and hierarchy of the node that will be generated relative to the **row element**.

So `PATH` mode gives you slightly more flexibility with output.

For example

```
select FirstName as "Name/First", LastName as "Name/Last" from #XmlTestTable FOR XML PATH
```

will give you xml like

```
<row>
  <Name>
    <First>John</First>
    <Last>Doe</Last>
  </Name>
</row>
// the rest of xml skipped
```

and this query

```
select FirstName as "@FirstName", LastName as "@LastName" from #XmlTestTable FOR XML path
```

will give you xml in following format:

```
<row FirstName="John" LastName="Doe" />
<row FirstName="Jane" LastName="Doe" />
<row FirstName="Brian" LastName="Smith" />
<row FirstName="Your" LastName="Mom" />
```

Or you can even mix attributes and elements in your output, say like:

```
select 
    FirstName + ' '  + LastName as "Name/@Full", 
    FirstName as "Name/First", 
    LastName as "Name/Last" 
from #XmlTestTable FOR XML path
```

will give you

```
<row>
  <Name Full="John Doe">
    <First>John</First>
    <Last>Doe</Last>
  </Name>
</row>
```

In your particular case output from two queries exactly the same just because you haven't specified "special" column names for `PATH` mode and used `ELEMENTS` option for `RAW` mode.

See MSDN for reference about [PATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) and [RAW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175140.aspx) modes.