# Sql ForXml; concatenating fields returning either a comma seperated list or empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml

I have looked through several SO questions on using FOR XML but have either missed, or not found anything specific to my query.

Fortunately, or perhaps not, the service to which I need to submit data wants the fields from my table(s) submitted as attributes rather than elements which means that I can use FOR XML AUTO.  However it does require some things that I'm not sure how to write the correct sql to achieve, and for which I would welcome some advice.

Some fields (let's say that I have three named Log1, Log2 and Log3) need to be returned as one attribute called for arguments sake Logs.  If all three log fields are Null then it needs to be an empty string, or if they contain data they need to be concatenated with a comma as the separator. I suspect that a simple Coalesce is not the answer here, but I'm not entirely sure what else would do.

As I said I would welcome some suggestions.  Thanks.

EDIT

Apologies, should have added some sql to assist.

```
SELECT  LandingId,
    VesselId,
    TicketNumber,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LandingDate1,112) AS landingdate1,
    Log1,
    Log2,
    Log3,
    COALESCE(VesselName,'') AS vesselName,
    VesselOwner
FROM Landings.LandingHeaders AS sale  FOR XML AUTO
```

Log1, Log2 and Log3 should become logs and be either an empty string if all are null or a comma separated list if they contain data.

EDIT2 (current Output with VesselName and Owner removed to preserve confidentiality)

```
<sale LandingId="3388" VesselId="1" TicketNumber="1         " landingdate1="20130705" />
```

Ass the Log values are null nothing is being returned,  Not sure if I can use a form of coalesce to either produce the empty string or a comma separated list.
I do know that I need to trim the ticketNumber.

Comment: if you add some example data, the query you are using now and the expected result we will be able to help you much better

Comment: If you will provide your desired xml structure as well as your sql scheme and some of your query attempts - it will be much easier to suggest something. Right now your question is not much readable and clear.

Comment: Have added sql, my apologies for not having done so earlier.

Comment: ok, great. And what about desired xml structure? How should it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use not `for xml auto`, but `for xml path` since it gives you much more flexibility.

Your desired goal (if I understood it correctly), can be achieved like this (I've skipped some fields)

```
select
    VesselId as '@VesselId',
    TicketNumber as '@TicketNumber',
    isnull(Log1 + ',', '') + isnull(Log2 + ',', '') + isnull(Log3 + ',', '') as '@Log123'
from Landings.LandingHeaders for xml path('sale')
```

**update**

Frankly, in your particular case you can achive your goal using `for xml auto` too, key idea of concatenating fields like

```
isnull(Log1 + ',', '') + isnull(Log2 + ',', '') + isnull(Log3 + ',', '')
```

to get empty string if all three fields are nulls and non-empty string with some data otherwise remains the same.

Comment: Many thanks Andy that's great.  I'd come up with ; COALESCE( CONCAT('',RTRIM(Log1), ',',RTRIM(Log2),',',RTRIM(Log3)),'') AS logs which does work but your solution is neater.  I'm very new to FOR XML, so what is the benefit of Path over AUTO?

Comment: @DomSinclair as I've said - `path` gives you much more flexibility than `auto`. You can have a look to my another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259623/query-results-same-when-using-xml-raw-element-and-xml-path/29260055#29260055) where I've provided some details about it.

Comment: Thank you Andy, +1 for your other answer as it explains it nicely.

Comment: Andy, Just noticed that output for null values includes commas, eg <sale vesseID="2" logs=",," />
<sale vesseID="1" logs="L7014,L7015,L7016" />
<sale vesseID="22" logs=",," />  How does one just return a plain empty string if logs are NULL?

Comment: Ignore that I'm mistaken, typo on my part.

Comment: @DomSinclair this behaviour is possible if you're using your approach with `concat` since it converts nulls to empty strings, so `concat(null, ',', null)` will produce `,` as result, but `isnull(null + ',', '') + isnull(null + ',', '')` will return empty string.